# how to use tesseract-ocr in php on linux os step by step

Tags: php

I am new in tesseract-ocr.plz guide me out how to use tesseract-ocr.I am totally new on this topic.

```
include 'tesseract.php';
$api= new TessBaseAPI;
$api->Init(".","eng",$mode_or_oem=OEM_DEFAULT);
$api->SetPageSegMode(PSM_AUTO);

$mImgFile = "eurotext.jpg";
$handle=fopen($mImgFile,"rb");
$mBuffer=fread($handle,filesize($mImgFile));
print strlen($mBuffer);
$result=ProcessPagesBuffer($mBuffer,strlen($mBuffer)*4,$api);
print "result(ProcessPagesBuffer)=";
print $result;
$result = ProcessPagesFileStream($mImgFile,$api);
print "result(ProcessPagesFileStream)=";
print $result;
```

?>
 but it shows Fatal error: Call to undefined function dl() in /var/www/html/prasenjit/OCR/tesseract.php on line 22

Comment: This has nothing to do with the use of `tesseract-ocr` and everything to do with your server not having the [`dl()`](http://php.net/dl) function enabled. Please READ the error message!

Comment: how to enable dl() on linux server

Comment: Actually I want to use tesseract-ocr for convert image file to text file and read it clearly..Plz any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

[From the maual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.dl.php):

> Warning
>   This function has been removed from some SAPIs in PHP 5.3.

and

> dl() is now disabled in some SAPIs due to stability issues. The only SAPIs that allow dl() are CLI and Embed. Use the [Extension Loading Directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension) instead.

You need to contact your host and confirm that this extension is available to you. It apparently is not.

Comment: Actually I want to use tesseract-ocr for convert image file to text file and read it clearly..Plz any one help me out.